# GLEW with CMakeLists

Tags: cmake, glew

I have the following CMakeLists to include glew into my project. Compiling the project works fine but when I run the project I get an error saying that the program can't find glew32.dll. Any ideas why?? Thanks for answers!

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/glew-1.12.0")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/glew-1.12.0/lib/Release/Win32/")
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

if(GLEW_FOUND)

message("GLEW Found!")

include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_libraries(${GLEW_LIBRARIES})

add_definitions(${GLEW_DEFINITIONS})

else(GLEW_FOUND)

message(FATAL_ERROR "GLEW NOT Found")

endif(GLEW_FOUND)


add_executable(Project ${CODE})

target_link_libraries(Project ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: What content of `GLEW_LIBRARIES` variable is? Check, that files listed in it exists. BTW, no need to `link_libraries` there: variable is solely for `target_link_libraries()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the directory where `glew32.dll` can be found in your environment's PATH variable. If you're using MSVC set the `Environment` textbox in your property pages of your application:

`PATH=<dir-of-glew32.dll>;%PATH%`

If you're running from shell, issue the same command on the command line.

Another option is to use `GLEW` as a static library. In that case you will not need `glew32.dll`, the entire glew library will be linked into your program. Check out the [GLEW github repository](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew) and study the script `cmake-testbuild.sh` about how to use GLEW as a static library. 
Please note, that the [GLEW github repository](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew) does not contain certain generated files. If you can't run `make extensions` on your platform, use this repository: [glew-with-extensions](https://github.com/tamaskenez/glew-with-extensions) which already contains the generated files.